# Labels of a particular font family won't appear

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have created an application and deployed it on around 70 PCs of my organization. On all the PCs it works perfect except for one.

On one system, all the labels of a particular font family (`century-gothic`) do not appear.

I have tried installing that font manually on that PC, but that didn't help.

Comment: Does the font work in other programs on that PC? If not, you might want to ask this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help) because it wouldn't be a programming-related question in that case.

Comment: You may want to consider to add that Font to the Project Resources, to embed it in your assembly. Then use a [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection) to make it available to your UI controls.